# Not able to convert the Realtime Database code to Firestore code

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to configure the database for the firestore database, but not able to do so, facing several errors, and not getting any particular solution for that, I am using swift for ios, it is basically a chat app followed from the codelab tutorial, here's the link to the same tutorial! this tutorial is based on Firebase Realtime database, and my requirement is of Firestore database,

thanks in advance for the guidance

What I Tried for converting to firestore database

```
var messages: [DocumentSnapshot]! = []
 fileprivate var _refHandle: CollectionReference!
 var ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("messages")

  func configureDatabase() {
    //ref = Firestore.firestore()    // Listen for new messages in the Firebase database
    _refHandle = self.ref.addSnapshotListener{ querySnapshot, error in
        if let documents = querySnapshot?.documents {
            var messages = [DocumentSnapshot]()
            for document in documents {
                let message = messages(snapshot: document)
                message.append(message)
                message.clientTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: message.messages.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)

            }
           // completion(messages)
        }
        } as! CollectionReference


  }
```

RealtimeDatabase Code

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
  var messages: [DataSnapshot]! = []
  fileprivate var _refHandle: DatabaseHandle?

  deinit {
    if let refHandle = _refHandle {
        self.ref.removeObserver(withHandle: _refHandle)
    }
}

func configureDatabase() {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    // Listen for new messages in the Firebase database
    _refHandle = self.ref.child("messages").observe(.childAdded, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) -> Void in
      guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
      strongSelf.messages.append(snapshot)
      strongSelf.clientTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: strongSelf.messages.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    })
  }
```

Error in firestore Code

```
Cannot call value of non-function type '[DocumentSnapshot]'"
```

at

```
let message = messages(snapshot: document)
```

Comment: Please do not re-post questions if you're not getting an immediate response.  If you have changes to make to an original post, please just edit the post.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/58636846/807126

Comment: What's the problem with the Firestore code you wrote?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it is giving error "Cannot call value of non-function type '[DocumentSnapshot]'" at let message = messages(snapshot: document) in firestore code

Comment: @DougStevenson I thought that reposting might get a response, I will take care from next time, Please accept Apology

Comment: Please add the error message, stack trace, and the exact line where this happens into your question. Note that this exact same comment thread happened on your previous post, so we're duplicating effort here.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added the error code in the question, Please assist further, thank you, I am a newbie to swift coding, thanks

Comment: `messages` is an array, so I doubt `messages(snapshot: document)` is a correct way to access it. What do you think this line is supposed to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen all I need is to retrieve messages from the database, that's what I thought

Comment: It would also help to understand your Firebase RTDB existing structure and then what you want it to look like in Firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not help but here's a function that reads in all messages and prints the message id (documentId) and the message text to console. Assume we have a class var messsagesArray set up to store each message and a class that hold the documentId and the message text.

Assume this structure

```
messages //the collection
   msg_id_0 //the document id
      msgText "Hello"
   msg_id_1
      msgText:"World"
```

and the code to read and print the messages

```
func readAllMessages() {
    let messagesCollection = self.db.collection("messages")
    messagesCollection.getDocuments(completion: { snapshot, err in

        if let err = err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        for doc in snapshot!.documents {
            let key = doc.documentID
            let msg = doc.get("msg") as! String
            let aMsg = MessageClass(aKey: key, msgText: msg)

            self.messagesArray.append(aMsg)
        }

        for msg in self.messagesArray { //output the read messages to console
            print(msg.key, msg.msgText)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: sorry this didn't worked, as I have to change a lot many things and code is already a huge one

Comment: @ramneek That code does work as it was pulled from an existing project. It's possible you don't understand the code or your implementation may be different or your Firestore structure is different. Can you explain what isn't working? The code in your question is incorrect and obviously isn't working so more details would help us to help you.

Comment: Jay, I did understood the code you shared, but my implementation is a different one, I have to change many more things to make your code working, I didn't doubt that your code is not working, definitely it is working and will be useful to someone else, but my case is little different, I appreciate your effort